# How to create a SQL view to show unbooked rooms

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have had a SQL testing with SQL Server 2012 to show a list of unbooked rooms for every day in the last month. The test does not allow to use stored procedure.

I have no idea how to get the result with querying only.

Here is the room table:

```
room no.
room 1
room 2
room 3
room 4
```

Here is the booking table:

```
date         room no.
1/1/2017     room 2
2/1/2017     room 2
2/1/2017     room 3
3/1/2017     room 2
3/1/2017     room 3
4/1/2017     room 2
4/1/2017     room 3
4/1/2017     room 4
```

Expected result (the rooms that are not in the booking table for each day):

```
date         room no.         status
1/1/2017     room 1            unbooking 
1/1/2017     room 3            unbooking
1/1/2017     room 4            unbooking
2/1/2017     room 1            unbooking
2/1/2017     room 4            unbooking
3/1/2017     room 1            unbooking
3/1/2017     room 4            unbooking
4/1/2017     room 1            unbooking
```

Comment: very unclear to me.

Comment: very unclear to me

Comment: @KamilIbadov I am asking royalties on my comment that was copyrighted

Comment: @ThomasG LOL :)

Comment: The result is the rooms that are not in the booking table for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
select
  "dates"."date" as "date",
  "rooms"."room no." as "room no.",
  'unbooking' as "status"
from (
  values
    ('1/1/2017'),
    ('2/1/2017'),
    ('3/1/2017'),
    ('4/1/2017')
) as "dates"("date")
cross join "rooms"
where not exists (
  select *
  from "bookings"
  where "bookings"."date" = "dates"."date"
  and "bookings"."room no." = "rooms"."room no."
)
```

Comment: It opens my eyes. Thank you melpomene.

Answer (score 0):

So it was answered in the meantime by melpomene.

And that answer includes exactly my suggestion at the bottom of this answer of mine: a calendar table - even if as an in-line Common Table Expression, consisting of only 4 days ...

Very probably, you're looking for the rooms that are not booked within all the dates that have any bookings within your `booking` table. So the status should be 'unbooked' or 'not booked' or 'vacant', if my assumption is true.

Your expected results, though, point into the same direction. Thanks for that.

(this is also again a proof that our skills must include making sense out of something that is not all too obvious at the start, and overcome any language barriers among us whose native language is not English ... :-] )

If I did not guess right, guneverdie, then the answer is, of course, wrong.

But, otherwise, here goes:

```
WITH 
-- start of input
rooms(room_no) AS (
          SELECT 'room 1'
UNION ALL SELECT 'room 2'
UNION ALL SELECT 'room 3'
UNION ALL SELECT 'room 4'
)
,
bookings(bookdate,room_no) AS (
          SELECT DATE '2017-01-01','room 2'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-02','room 2'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-02','room 3'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-03','room 2'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-03','room 3'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-04','room 2'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-04','room 3'
UNION ALL SELECT DATE '2017-01-04','room 4'
)
-- end of input; start of help tables
,
-- all possible dates from the bookings table
search_dates AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
  bookdate
FROM bookings
)
,
-- search arguments: 
-- all possible rooms and all possible dates
search_args AS (
SELECT
  bookdate
, room_no
FROM search_dates
CROSS JOIN rooms
)
-- end of help tables, final select
-- could also be a WHERE NOT EXISTS predicate
-- but I prefer a LEFT JOIN with a filter on NULLs
SELECT
  search_args.bookdate
, search_args.room_no
, 'unbooked' AS status
FROM search_args
LEFT JOIN bookings USING(bookdate,room_no)
WHERE bookings.room_no IS NULL
ORDER BY 1,2
;

bookdate  |room_no|status
2017-01-01|room 1 |unbooked
2017-01-01|room 3 |unbooked
2017-01-01|room 4 |unbooked
2017-01-02|room 1 |unbooked
2017-01-02|room 4 |unbooked
2017-01-03|room 1 |unbooked
2017-01-03|room 4 |unbooked
2017-01-04|room 1 |unbooked
```

The best design, though, would be to have a `calendar` table ready, with one row per day, so that you also get the vacant rooms on a day where there is no booking at all.

Happy playing

Marco the Sane